# In R using DT shiny datatable move the column selection to the top of the dataframe

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to move the column selection ability to be at the top of the dataframe instead of the bottom. I have no real need for the sorting ability that the current header provides so that can either get moved to the bottom or removed entirely. Would this be possible?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

mapping_list_headers <- mtcars

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Remove Extra Headers and Columns from Dataframe"),
  mainPanel(
    helpText("Select the rows/columns to remove by clicking on them."),
    actionButton("removeRows", "Remove Selected Rows"),
    actionButton("removeCols", "Remove Selected Columns"),
    actionButton("closeApp", "Close App and Session"),
    hr(),
    fluidRow(
      column(12, DT::dataTableOutput("data_table"))
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Sample dataframe
  data <- reactiveVal(mapping_list_headers)
  
  # Display dataframe in table format
  output$data_table <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(data(),selection = list(mode = 'multiple', target = 'row+column'))
  })
  
  # Remove selected rows
  observeEvent(input$removeRows, {
    if (!is.null(input$data_table_rows_selected)) {
      print(str(input))
      print((input))
      selected_rows <- input$data_table_rows_selected
      print(selected_rows)
      df_data <- data()
      df_data <- df_data[-selected_rows, , drop = FALSE]
      data(df_data)
    }
  })
  
  # Remove selected columns
  observeEvent(input$removeCols, {
    if (!is.null(input$data_table_columns_selected)) {
      selected_cols <- input$data_table_columns_selected
      print(selected_cols)
      df_data <- data()
      df_data <- df_data[, -selected_cols, drop = FALSE]
      data(df_data)
    }
  })
  
  # Close the app and session
  observeEvent(input$closeApp, {
    data_out <<- data()
    session$close()
    stopApp()
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Solution from @Stéphane Laurent implemented with removal of col/rows:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

callback <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'thead th', function() {",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('clickedCol', $(this).index(), {priority: 'event'});",
  "});"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  actionButton("removeSelectedRows", "Remove Selected Rows"),
  actionButton("removeSelectedColumns", "Remove Selected Columns"),
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Make a copy of the iris dataset
  data <- reactiveVal(iris)
  
  output$dtable <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      data(),
      selection = list(mode = 'multiple', target = 'row+column'),
      callback = JS(callback),
      options = list(
        ordering = FALSE # remove the sorting arrows
      )
    )
  })
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("dtable")
  
  selectedColumns <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$dtable_columns_selected, {
    selectedColumns(input$dtable_columns_selected)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$clickedCol, {
    j <- input$clickedCol
    selected_columns <- selectedColumns()
    if(j %in% selected_columns) {
      sel <- setdiff(selected_columns, j)
    } else {
      sel <- c(selected_columns, j)
    }
    selectColumns(proxy, sel)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$removeSelectedRows, {
    removeRows <- input$dtable_rows_selected
    if (!is.null(removeRows) && length(removeRows) > 0) {
      data(data()[-removeRows, ])
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$removeSelectedColumns, {
    removeCols <- selectedColumns()
    if (!is.null(removeCols) && length(removeCols) > 0) {
      data(data()[, -removeCols, drop = FALSE])
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way. Thanks to the JavaScript callback, when you click on a column header, the index of this column is attributed to the Shiny value `input$clickedCol`. Then, observing this Shiny value in the server, the selected columns are updated thanks to the **DT** function `selectColumns`. You can still select a column by clicking the footer.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)


callback <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'thead th', function() {",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('clickedCol', $(this).index(), {priority: 'event'});",
  "});"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$dtable <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris,
      selection = list(mode = 'multiple', target = 'row+column'),
      callback = JS(callback),
      options = list(
        ordering = FALSE # remove the sorting arrows
      )
    )
  })
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("dtable")
  
  selectedColumns <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$dtable_columns_selected, {
    selectedColumns(input$dtable_columns_selected)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  observe({
    print(input$dtable_columns_selected)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$clickedCol, {
    j <- input$clickedCol
    selected_columns <- selectedColumns()
    if(j %in% selected_columns) {
      sel <- setdiff(selected_columns, j)
    } else {
      sel <- c(selected_columns, j)
    }
    selectColumns(proxy, sel)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @megmac Maybe it is better to hide the columns rather than removing them, with `hideCols`.